# 'Can't create a regex expression from object

Tags: arrays, objective-c, xcode, crash

im facing this issue , i email textfiled the app crash

```
+(BOOL)isCorrectEmail:(NSString *)email{
    BOOL strictFilter = NO;
    NSString *strictFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Az-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})";
    NSString *lastString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]+";

    NSString *emailRegex = strictFilter ? strictFilterString : lastString;
    NSPredicate *emailPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES NO",emailRegex];

    return [emailPred evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES NO %@", emailRegex]; you are missing %@ at the end.

Comment: `@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];`